# Can I use apostrophe s to shorten "is"?

Tags: contractions, apostrophe

For example, I'd say:

The interview's on Monday.

Is that grammatically acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the contraction 's for "is" (and also for "has") is very common, particularly in speech and informal contexts; it may be considered bad style in a formal written context. For instance, using it in a conversational email would probably be considered acceptable, but in an essay or letter of complaint the full form would probably be expected.

That applies particularly to using it with:

- Nouns, like your example, or "the weather's awful today"
- Names, like "John's on holiday at the moment"

Even in relatively formal contexts, e.g. a newspaper article, it is common to use it with:

- Pronouns, like "he's rich", "it's raining"
- Other determiners, like "that's right", "what's on TV"

Comment: "The weather's awful today." is very common in speech. It is never used in written English except in highly colloquial contexts. **It is not a written form**. "He's rich" and "It's raining" are not common in newspaper writing but not because of the contractions. Because of style. That said: The Associated Press Stylebook: “Contractions reflect informal speech and writing. . . . Avoid excessive use of contractions.”

Comment: @Lambie The categorisation of certain pieces of written text as "spoken English" is not one that is particularly useful to a learner of English - for instance, it is not true that everything acceptable in speech is acceptable in an e-mail. The concept that is useful to a learner is that some forms are considered more formal or informal than others, and that written contractions are relatively informal, but would be acceptable in some contexts, such as in an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

- The interview's on Monday.

A contraction of the verb is with a noun is found in spoken English.

- The lesson's over. [The lesson **is** over]
- An apple's good for you. [An apple **is** good for you]
- The guard's gone. [The guard has gone]
- The guards've gone. [The guards have gone]
- They've left. [They have left.]
- The guests'll come later. [The guest will come later.]

These forms are not used in written English.
Written English versus spoken English.

And the contraction of is to apostrophe s, as in the question here: **The interview's on Monday** is **a perfectly respectable spoken form** and would not generally be used even in informal writing, say, in an informal memo, where other contractions might be used.

Bear in mind: Spoken English can be written down!

**They can be used if you are chatting online or text messaging, for instance** where you are using spoken language in written form.

**But don't put them in an essay, article, academic writing, questionnaire, instructions, manuals** etc.

Here is an academic article on this very subject:

My answer above is intended as a non-academic response to the question. Below is an academic response to this question.

The academic article below starts with this:

The main point is: the grammar of spoken English is not the grammar of written English. The article is about that. Is states:

> Teaching about talk – what do pupils need to know about spoken language
>   and the important ways in which talk differs from writing?
>
> Conclusion
>   It would be a mistake to assume that these forms of
>   grammar, **though common in spoken English, are exclusive to spoken
>   English.** For example, the relative immediacy of forms such as e-mail
>   communication, advertising copy, and some notes, letters and memos
>   means that informality is often the preferred style and that a
>   relative symmetry of relationship is deliberately constructed by such
>   choices.
>
> [spoken English](http://oro.open.ac.uk/376/1/coffin.pdf)

Comment: Downvoted as per comments above: the forms demonstrably _are_ used in written English, whether or not you approve of them.

Comment: The key word is "formal", not "written". They have a standardised written form, and will commonly be encountered in all sorts of informal writing that it is not consciously mimicking speech.

Comment: Reading the article convinced me that that there are grammatical forms that occur frequently in speech and rarely in writing, but contractions are hardly an example. Contractions occur in all kinds of writing. I think that the distinction between formal and informal communications is **primary** but does not **completely** capture the fact that some usages that are common in speech are quite rare in even highly informal writing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104297/discussion-between-lambie-and-jeff-morrow).